# unable to move data from register to variable

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

I want to create a program that read number from user and store it in variable `student_num`. The problem is that there is a problem when i try to store it, even though I tried to use different variable size `word` , `dword`  but it doesn't work . Does anyone have ideas on how to fix this?

Here is my assembly code:

```
;program to get grades and print out the average of the numbers and list of 
;numbers which is above average
;input: list of grades
;output: average,list of numbers above average
;author:george sobhy
.386
.MODEL flat

ExitProcess PROTO NEAR32 stdcall,dwExitCode:DWORD
INCLUDE io.h
cr      equ     0ah
Lf      equ     0dh
.STACK 4096 
.DATA

enter_stu_num byte        "Enter the number of the students: ",0
student_num   word        20 DUP(?)

.CODE
_start:
            mov average,0
            lea ebx,arr
            mov eax,0
            mov student_num,0
            
            output enter_stu_num
            input  student_num,11
            atod   student_num
            mov student_num,eax
            mov ecx,eax
            
            
            INVOKE ExitProcess, 0   ; exit with return code 0

PUBLIC _start                       ; make entry point public
END
```

Comment: Which line has the error? What is the error message? What assembler are you using? What processor is this? (I think the problem is at `mov student_num, eax` because `student_num` is a `word` but `eax` is a `dword`.)

Comment: yeah it worked but it is word 20 dup(?) .should one item of the array be  the same  size or bigger to store eax?

Comment: Just pick a size and use it consistently.

Comment: MASM-style assemblers associate a size with named variables; if you want to write a pair of words with one 32-bit register, you need to explicitly tell MASM you know what you're doing with `mov dword ptr [mem], eax`.  But very likely you should just use `dword` or `dd` instead of `word` to reserve space for your array of 20 elements.  (40 bytes currently, or 80 bytes if you keep the element count as 20 when widening the type.)

Comment: okay thank you all . i will use `ptr`